# Laravel Pivot table not found

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, tablename

**My goal.**
I have 3 Laravel models: *user*, *campaign* and *campaign_players*. I want to get info about a user, and also the campaigns he/she is playing.

**The problem.**
When I run this query :

```
$campaigns = user::with(['campaigns_playing'])->where('id', $id)->get();
```

it gives me this message:

> "Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'sagohamnen.campaign_players' doesn't exist (SQL: select
>   `sh_campaigns`.*, `campaign_players`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`,
>   `campaign_players`.`id` as `pivot_id` from `sh_campaigns` inner join
>   `campaign_players` on `sh_campaigns`.`id` = `campaign_players`.`id`
>   where `campaign_players`.`user_id` in (2))"

It looks like it can't find the table name, for some reason. Do you guys have any idea what causing the problem and how to fix it?

Here are short code pieces from my models and it´s database tables.

**User**

```
protected $table = 'sh_users';
public function campaigns_playing()
{
        return $this->belongsToMany('Sagohamnen\campaign\campaign', 'Sagohamnen\campaign\campaign_players', 'user_id', 'id');
 }

Schema::create('sh_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('name', 255);
});
```

**Campaign**

```
protected $table = 'sh_campaigns';

Schema::create('sh_campaigns', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('name', 255);               
        $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Campaign_players**

```
protected $table = 'sh_campaign_players';

Schema::create('sh_campaign_players', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('campaign_id')->unsigned();
        $table->date('date');
        $table->primary(['user_id', 'campaign_id']);
});
```

Comment: it looks like there may be a few things wrong here. The first error you get is that table `campaign_players` doesn't exist. From the code you have posted it seems you have named the table `sh_campaign_players`.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Yeah, I wrote the name of the model, called campaign_players. You mean I should write the MySql table name instead of the model?

Comment: what @Ruffles said is correct about how to pass the name of the table. In addition I would encourage you to read the Laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships). There are certain conventions which are encouraged. Such as calling the pivot table `campaign_user` in this case.

Comment: Thanks. I considered changing it to campaign_users, though I thought campaign_player would be more logical, for my purpose.

Comment: I certainly agree that naming things to fit your case is a good idea. Since it is a Laravel convention though, if you were to use `campaign_user` for example, you would only need to pass one argument to your `belongsToMany` and Laravel will imply the rest, rather than you needing to be explicit about everything. [And you can still name the methods however you see fit like `campaignsPlaying`]. But again, just a suggestion, do what makes sense for your case :)

Comment: Yeah the benefits is interesting indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the pivot table name as second parameter to the belongsToMany() method. It asks for a string, not a model class path.

Change `Sagohamnen\campaign\campaign_players` to `sh_campaign_players` (or whatever the name of your pivot table is in the database)